# Working with stale data when performing asynchronous jobs with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, sidekiq

In order to process events asynchronously and create an activity feed, I'm using Sidekiq and Ruby on Rails' Global ID.

This works well for most types of activities, however some of them require data that could change by the time the job is performed.

Here's a completely made-up example:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
  value :score # stores an integer in Redis

  has_many :likes

  def popular?
    likes.count > 1000
  end
end
```

And a Sidekiq worker performing a job every time a movie is updated:

```
class MovieUpdatedWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(global_id)
    movie = GlobalID::Locator.locate(global_id)
    MovieUpdatedActivity.create(movie: movie, score: movie.score) if movie.popular?
  end
end
```

Now, imagine Sidekiq is lagging behind and, before it gets a chance to perform its job, the movie's `score` is updated in Redis, some users unliked the movie and the `popular` method now returns false.

*Sidekiq ends up working with updated data.*

I'm looking for ways to schedule jobs while making sure the required data won't change when the job is performed. A few ideas:

1/ Manually pass in all the required data and adjust the worker accordingly:

```
MovieUpdatedWorker.perform_async(
  movie: self,
  score: score,
  likes_count: likes.count
)
```

This could work but would require reimplementing/duplicating all methods that rely on data such as `score` and `popular?` (imagine an app with much more than these two/three movable pieces).

This doesn't scale well either since serialized objects could take up a lot of room in Redis.

2/ Stubbing some methods on the record passed in to the worker:

```
MovieUpdatedWorker.perform_async(
  global_id,
  stubs: { score: score, popular?: popular? }
)

class MovieUpdatedWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(global_id, stubs: {})
    movie = GlobalID::Locator.locate(global_id)

    # inspired by RSpec
    stubs.each do |message, return_value|
      movie.stub(message) { return_value }
    end

    MovieUpdatedActivity.create(movie: movie, score: movie.score) if movie.popular?
  end
end
```

This isn't functional, but you can imagine the convenience of dealing with an actual record, not having to reimplement existing methods, and dealing with the actual data.

Do you see other strategies to "freeze" object data and asynchronously process them? What do you think about these two?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that the data was stale since you would actually have the newest version of it, just that it was no longer popular. It sounds like you actually want the stale version.

If you don't want the data to have changed you need to cache it somehow. Either like you say, pass the data to the job directly, or You can add some form of versioning of the data in the database and pass a reference to the old version.

I think passing on the data you need to Redis is a reasonable way. You could serialize only the attributes you actually care about, like score.

Comment: You're right, I fixed the title and rephrased the question. Thanks!